# while opening crystal reports in displays hexadecimal value

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports

I'm working on Visual Studio 2008 to develop a web application in asp.net.

if I add a crystal report file (.rpt) in my project, I see only hexadecimal code.

I obviously miss something, previously it worked in my system. Recently I formatted my system, and installed vs2008, then the problem arises...im in need..

Please help me to find the solution.. thanks in advance